# Using android device's internal secondary memory & data not get lost during uninstall of application

Tags: android, memory

Is there any way to store something in the secondary memory of the device & it not getting removed with the uninstall of the application in android? I did a lot of research & couldnot find any information, I don't want to use the data/data// to be used because the data would be lost if I uninstall the application. If this cannot be done, why? Because as per my intuition, tablet's secondary memory should behave just like SD card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a folder outside of the apps storage and in the external storage directory it should remain.  See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Specifically 'getExternalStorageDirectory()'

**From Android Documentation**

> public static File getExternalStorageDirectory ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Return the primary external storage directory.
>   This directory may not currently be accessible if it has been mounted
>   by the user on their computer, has been removed from the device, or
>   some other problem has happened. You can determine its current state
>   with getExternalStorageState().
>
> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.
>
> On devices with multiple users (as described by UserManager), each
>   user has their own isolated external storage. Applications only have
>   access to the external storage for the user they're running as.
>
> In devices with multiple "external" storage directories, this
>   directory represents the "primary" external storage that the user will
>   interact with. Access to secondary storage is available through
>
> Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in
>   order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are
>   private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by
>   Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the system will take care of
>   deleting if the application is uninstalled. Other shared files should
>   be placed in one of the directories returned by
>   getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String).
>
> Writing to this path requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission,
>   and starting in read access requires the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   permission, which is automatically granted if you hold the write
>   permission.
>
> Starting in KITKAT, if your application only needs to store internal
>   data, consider using getExternalFilesDir(String) or
>   getExternalCacheDir(), which require no permissions to read or write.
>
> This path may change between platform versions, so applications should
>   only persist relative paths.

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory gives me '/storage/emulated/0' which I dont know whether is the correct internal storage address, please let me know what you think.